# How to determine Route Prefix programmatically in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I wanted to provide some URL separation for my public/anonymous controllers and views from the admin/authenticated controllers and views.  So I ended up using entirely [Attribute Routing](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2013/11/attribute-routing-with-aspnet-mvc-5.html) in order to take more control of my URLs.  I wanted my public URLs to start with "~/Admin/etc." while my public URLs would not have any such prefix.

### Public Controller (one of several)

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { //etc. }
}
```

### Admin Controller (one of several)

```
[RoutePrefix("Admin/People")]
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { //etc. }
}
```

This allows me to have public URLs such as:

```
http://myapp/home/someaction
```

...and admin/authenticated URLs such as:

```
http://myapp/admin/people/someaction
```

But now I want to do some dynamic stuff in the views based on whether the user is in the Admin section or the Public section of the site.  How can I access this programmatically, properly?

I know I could do something like

```
if (Request.Url.LocalPath.StartsWith("/Admin"))
```

...but it feels "hacky."  I know I can access the controller and action names via

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
```

...but the "admin" piece isn't reflected in there, because it's just a route prefix, not an actual controller name.

**So, the basic question is, how do I programmatically determine whether the currently loaded view is under the "admin" section or not?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to reflect the `RoutePrefixAttribute` from the `Controller` type, and then get its `Prefix` value. The `Controller` instance is available on the `ViewContext`.

This example creates a handy HTML helper that wraps all of the steps into a single call.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class RouteHtmlHelpers
{
    public static string GetRoutePrefix(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        // Get the controller type
        var controllerType = helper.ViewContext.Controller.GetType();

        // Get the RoutePrefix Attribute
        var routePrefixAttribute = (RoutePrefixAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
            controllerType, typeof(RoutePrefixAttribute));

        // Return the prefix that is defined
        return routePrefixAttribute.Prefix;
    }
}
```

Then in your view, you just need to call the extension method to get the value of the `RoutePrefixAttribute`.

```
@Html.GetRoutePrefix() // Returns "Admin/People"
```

Comment: Cool! I think that works well.  I only tweaked the return from the extension method to account for situations where there is no prefix defined (like in my public controller). `return routePrefixAttribute != null ? routePrefixAttribute.Prefix : null;`

Comment: In AttributeRouting 3.5.6.0, the property is `Url` instead of `Prefix`.

Comment: This worked. I didn't need the prefix from a view since I was making an API so I tweaked the extension method to take an ApiController instead so it could be used under the hood. Thanks!

Comment: one-liner: `helper.ViewContext.Controller.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<RoutePrefixAttribute>.Prefix`